# iMessage Style Receding Keyboard in an iOS App

Tags: iphone, keyboard, uikit, ios5

I've been wondering if it is possible to replicate the behavior of Apple's iOS5 keyboard in the messages app, without using any private API calls. When you scroll down past the keyboard in the messages app, the keyboard will collapse leaving more room to see messages - try it to see.

I couldn't find anything that points towards making this without having to start jumping through some serious hoops to get an instance of the Keyboard's View. And I'm pretty sure Apple wouldn't be happy with that.

In addition to the answer given below you can see a fully baked xcode project of my implementation here:
https://github.com/orta/iMessage-Style-Receding-Keyboard

Comment: I've been wondering this too - would be great if someone has come up with a solution. I'm assuming that by 'receding' you mean the new keyboard behavior in iOS 5 for the messages app?

Comment: I'm quite sure all that's done is keyboard's context being rendered into a bitmap and the rest is magic (ie tracking scroll position, moving the rendered image back and forth, etc..)

Comment: Wish I could Up-vote this more than once.  This is exactley what I've been looking for.  Thank you!

Comment: do any other iOS5 apps show this behavior?

Comment: I don't see anyway you could do this without private API calls.

Comment: I've not seen any other apps show this behaviour...

I don't think you can do the bitmap rendering without coming up with the same problem I had in making the above version, when resigning first responder, the Keyboard will always show the animation from its natural position. 

This means you would still have to access the other window and hide the view so that you don't see a phantom keyboard animation.

Comment: Instagram has this behaviour. @jasongregori

Comment: @nickw444 wow, you're totally right. I see David's solution down there doesn't use private API calls, but it does access private views which I would still be wary about.

Comment: This is obviously a biased opinion, but if you're looking for a way to implement this keyboard functionality in a drop-in manner that works with all sorts of view types, I would recommend DAKeyboardControl: https://github.com/danielamitay/DAKeyboardControl

Comment: @DanielAmitay It has some crashes in it in swizzled_addSubView. It adds sub view to the deallocated instance

Comment: I usee https://github.com/oseparovic/MessageComposerView on all my projects, simple and fast to implement on your projects.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is an incomplete solution, however it should give you a good starting point.

Add the following ivars to your UIViewController:

```
CGRect        keyboardSuperFrame; // frame of keyboard when initially displayed
UIView      * keyboardSuperView;  // reference to keyboard view
```

Add an inputAccessoryView to your text controller. I created an small view to insert as the accessoryView:

```
accView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
accView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
textField.inputAccessoryView = accView;
```

I added the above code to `-(void)loadView`

Register to receive UIKeyboardDidShowNotification and UIKeyboardDidHideNotification when view is loaded:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
        name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
        object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:)
        name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
        object:nil];
    return;
}
```

Add methods to specified as the selectors for the notifications:

```
// method is called whenever the keyboard is about to be displayed
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // makes keyboard view visible incase it was hidden
    keyboardSuperView.hidden = NO;
    return;
}
// method is called whenever the keyboard is displayed
- (void) keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)note
{
    // save reference to keyboard so we can easily determine
    // if it is currently displayed
    keyboardSuperView  = textField.inputAccessoryView.superview;

    // save current frame of keyboard so we can reference the original position later
    keyboardSuperFrame = textField.inputAccessoryView.superview.frame;
    return;
}
```

Add methods to track touched and update keyboard view:

```
// stops tracking touches to divider
- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGRect newFrame;
    CGRect bounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    newFrame = keyboardSuperFrame;
    newFrame.origin.y = bounds.size.height;  

    if ((keyboardSuperView.superview))
        if (keyboardSuperFrame.origin.y != keyboardSuperView.frame.origin.y)
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                    animations:^{keyboardSuperView.frame = newFrame;}
                    completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                keyboardSuperView.hidden = YES;
                                keyboardSuperView.frame = keyboardSuperFrame;
                                [textField resignFirstResponder]; }];
    return;
}


// updates divider view position based upon movement of touches
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   UITouch  * touch;
   CGPoint    point;
   CGFloat    updateY;

   if ((touch = [touches anyObject]))
   {
      point   = [touch locationInView:self.view];
      if ((keyboardSuperView.superview))
      {
         updateY = keyboardSuperView.frame.origin.y;
         if (point.y < keyboardSuperFrame.origin.y)
            return;
         if ((point.y > updateY) || (point.y < updateY))
            updateY = point.y;
         if (keyboardSuperView.frame.origin.y != updateY)
            keyboardSuperView.frame = CGRectMake(keyboardSuperFrame.origin.x,
                                                 point.y,
                                                 keyboardSuperFrame.size.width,
                                                 keyboardSuperFrame.size.height);
      };
   };
   return;
}
```

Disclaimers:

- When resigning as first responded, the keyboard moves back to its original position before sliding off screen.  To make dismissing the keyboard more fluid, you first need to create an animation to move the keyboard off of the screen and then hide the view.  I'll leave this part as an exercise to the readers.
- I've only tested this on the iOS 5 simulator and with an iPhone with iOS 5.  I have not tested this with earlier versions of iOS.

The SlidingKeyboard project I created to test this concept is available from GitHub in the examples directory of BindleKit:

https://github.com/bindle/BindleKit

Edit: Updating example to address first disclaimer.

Comment: I think this is a good implementation, and without a lot of the messing I had to do to get to the keyboard.

Comment: The trick of using the inputAccessoryView to get a handle for the keyboard works in iOS 4.

Comment: Small bug fix: when dragging the keyboard up, if you drag too fast, the keyboard won't 'stick' up, and will instead be resigned.  This can be fixed by replacing `if (point.y < keyboardSuperFrame.origin.y)
            return;` with `if (point.y < keyboardSuperFrame.origin.y) {                
                if (keyboardSuperView.frame.origin.y != keyboardSuperFrame.origin.y) {                  
                    keyboardSuperView.frame = keyboardSuperFrame;
                }
                return;
            }`

Comment: Another issue: If your view does not take up the whole window, the touch points may be a bit off (in my case, by 64 points: 44 for the navigation bar, 20 for the status bar).  I fixed this replacing self.view with [self.view window] in the line `point   = [touch locationInView:self.view];`

Comment: It looks like this shows the correct animation for iOS 8 and below. On iOS 9, the animation is gone. The keyboard will only dismiss without animation!

Comment: found the solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32632207/cant-move-keyboard-view-ios9-swift

Answer (score 50):

In iOS 7 there is a keyboardDismissMode property on UIScrollView.
So just set it to "UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive" and you'll get this behavior. Works in UIScrollView subclasses such as UITableView.

```
self.tableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive;
```

**Swift 3:**

```
tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
```

Or change it in storyboard (if using it) in attributes inspector for your UIScrollView subclass.

Comment: and how do you track the current keyboard position?

Comment: @JoãoNunes I don't know, this one for easy case - with scroll views where everything regarding keyboard position happens automatically. If you're not asking about keyboard notifications...

Comment: when you send the keyboard down. And you want to adjust the UI according to the Keyboard position. How do you know the keyboard frame at that point? or how do you get notifications for the keyboard movement?

Comment: @JoãoNunes usually you listen to UIKeyboardNotifications. But as far as i know they only tell you things like "will show keyboard" "will hide keyboard". If you need to change your UI based on exact keyboard frame, that's different question really, beyond the scope of this.

Comment: it is in the scope of your answer. Cause when you have the interactive mode, you need to track where is the keyboard or at least you need to track something that let you know the percentage of interaction.
In iMessage APP when the keyboard goes up and down. the input field also moves up and down!

Comment: @JoãoNunes Yes, everything goes up and down, but in scroll view subclasses (as table view) you get this "for free". That's why this new keyboard mode is cool.

Comment: Nice documentation digging. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Vladimir's simple solution will hide the keyboard as the user scrolls down. However to finish the question regarding iMessage, in order to keep a TextField always visible and anchored to the top of the keyboard, you need to implement these methods:

```
- (UIView *) inputAccessoryView {
     // Return your textfield, buttons, etc
}

- (BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}
```

[Here's a good tutorial](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/input-accessorizing-uiviewcontroller) breaking it down more

Comment: This actually is the *correct* way of implementing iMessage-style message input toolbar... Wow.. I can't believe how complicated Apple made it to be, and at the same time, how it was right in front of me all along. Anyways, THANKS!