# iMessage style chatbox recede with keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've done lots of searching and implemented several snippets of code I have found from similarly asked questions.

I've used several answered questions like this one: [iMessage Style Receding Keyboard in an iOS App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780753/imessage-style-receding-keyboard-in-an-ios-app)

to get a receding keyboard set up. That works perfectly! I am able to scroll down and once my finger hits the keyboard it begins sliding down until I let go then it pops off screen. Now my issue is getting the `UITextView` right above the keyboard to act like it does in iMessage. What i want is once my finger hits the top of the UITextView, or the place where my message is written to start sliding off as well.

DaKeyboardControl is broken on iOS 8 so thats not an option, and I'd prefer not to use a third party custom API.

Again my question is how to get the keyboard and the textview (used to type out your message) to slide down down once my finger hits the textView. Right now my finger slides past the textView, then once it hits the keyboard it starts sliding off. I don't want my finger to pass the textView before it starts sliding. Here is a video of what i'm talking about:
http://d.pr/v/8Pa6

Comment: Looking at the Messages app, what `UITextView` are you referring to that should slide off the screen?

Comment: @Stonz2 in my app I have a a UITextView with constraints all around it next to the send button, not totally sure how its all set up in the Messages app but I'm referring to the view that contains the text you are typing out next to the send button. The swipe down gesture in the messages app interacts with that textView as well as the keyboard, mine doesn't. only the keyboard

Comment: here is an example of what I'm looking at http://d.pr/v/8Pa6

Comment: So, what you're saying is that you want the keyboard & `UITextView` to begin sliding down when the touch reaches the top of the `UITextView` instead of waiting until the touch reaches the keyboard?

Comment: exactly, thats what I'd like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've followed the linked tutorial in your question. I'll refer to your view that holds the `UITextView` and "Send" button as simply `textView` in the code.

You need to include the frame of `textView` in the calculation of where the touches are happening and when things need to move. Also, keep an instance variable of `previousY` that will hold the `y` coordinate of where the touch moved from.

In `touchesMoved` method:

```
...
//updateY = keyboardSuperView.frame.origin.y;
if (point.y < keyboardSuperFrame.origin.y - textView.frame.size.height)
   return;

//if(point.y < previousY || point.y > previousY)
//{
//    previousY = point.y;
    updateY = point.y + textView.frame.size.height;
//}
...
```

Let me know if you have any issues with this, because I haven't actually tested anything.

---

EDIT: As brought to my attention by [@Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661346/sam), the second `if` conditional that I had was very unnecessary. Regardless of whether the `y` val changes or not, the 3rd `if` (not shown) will still only fire if the `y` val changes without the 2nd `if`. Only need to set `updateY`.

Comment: Is that second conditional necessary?

Comment: It is (somewhat) in the big picture. Only if the y value changes will the keyboard frame change happen. By checking the updated `y` val in the 3rd conditional that isn't shown, you can avoid a pointless frame change.

Comment: @Sam After thinking about it more I realized that you're still right. Updated the post accordingly.