# Translate Keyboard Sideways Similar to iMessage App

Tags: ios, animation, keyboard

Currently, I am trying to create a view very similar to the iMessage app. In the app when the user swipes to the right the individual conversation view moves out of the the right side of the screen along with the keyboard. I got the view to move but how would I go about getting the keyboard to translate with a pangesture. So far I have tried adding an inputAccessoryView to my Textbox and stored the keyboard view to a holder view

```
func keyboardDidShow(notification:NSNotification) {
keyboardSuperView = textBox.inputAccessoryView?.superview
}
```

but when I tried to change to the frame for this view nothing happened. What is the best way to go about doing this?

I followed the example in this post but it didn't work: [iMessage Style Receding Keyboard in an iOS App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780753/imessage-style-receding-keyboard-in-an-ios-app)